Imask - How to install in VS code?
First time trying to install a library in a project. I found this library as a suggestion to mask input fields in my form. I consulted this page : https://imask.js.org/guide.html and tried what is explained there but can't get it to work :(

My script.js is importe as a type="module" in my HTML file to be able to use import properly
I used the command line : npm install imask
I added this line at the top of my script.js file : import IMask from 'imask'

I get this error message :
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "imask". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
index.html
<script type="module" src="js/script.js"></script>

script.js
import IMask from 'imask';

I tried changing the import path in the script.js file :
import IMask from '../node_modules/imask';

and it gave me this error message :
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
Then, I tried this path :
import IMask from '../node_modules/imask/dist/imask';

and it gave me this error message :
GET http://000.0.0.0:0000/node_modules/imask/dist/imask 404 (Not Found)
